# How do I exit watch which runs without any errors?

Tags: linux, watch

I'm running a watch to run some commands with ; I want it to get exited after some time & I don't have 'timeout', just like creating reports for some time with fixed interval.

Comment: You can do it with a for loop instead of watch command.

Comment: In for Loop There's sleep in between 2 commands, so after completion of these few commands I need to exit and avoid the last sleep too, hence I need watch to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
interval=2
n=3
cmd="ls"

for ((i=1;i<=$n;i++)) {
    $cmd
    [ $i -eq $n ] || sleep $interval
}
```

Comment: fulfilling my requirement, just thought like if I could do that with watch.

Comment: I tried to find out the options fulfilling your requirement in the manual of watch but I got nothing. Maybe watch itself doesn't support that function.